# Why can't you take a hoverboard on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, safety, hand-luggage

As Delta Airlines' online check-in helpfully informs me

[image]

> **Examples** of Forbidden Dangerous items include paints, lighter fluid, fireworks, tear gases, oxygen bottles, radiopharmaceuticals, and hoverboards.

Is this a standard text? Does it have some actual precedent, is it a deliberate allusion to the [don't stuff beans up your nose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don't_stuff_beans_up_your_nose) trope, or just a flat-out joke? Why don't they give something actually realistic as example for the hazards a hoverboard would bring?

Comment: google 'lithium battery fire'. it's not a joke, and all airlines have that rule now.

Comment: They have a tendency to [spontaneously combust](https://bestelectrichoverboard.com/hoverboards-exploding-which-hoverboards-are-safe/), a bad thing on an aircraft.

Comment: @Aganju well there are plenty of appliances with lithium batteries. Something as outlandish as a hoverboard seems an odd representative for them...

Comment: As you won't be able to talk them out of it, you could explore hoverboard rentals. Make sure it's not a cheap one . . . they still catch fire.

Comment: Hoverboards tend to need especially high-capacity batteries, and they have to be designed to allow high current to flow, since the motor needs a lot of power.  So they're more susceptible to catch fire than something like a laptop or phone, and there's a lot more lithium battery to burn if they do.

Comment: Also, there was a particularly notorious epidemic of early-model hoverboards catching fire, which led to knee-jerk regulations targeting hoverboards specifically.

Comment: @NateEldredge Not sure it's really a knee-jerk. As you say, a lot of them caught fire, and that kind of fire on a plane is a serious danger to hundreds of lives.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Sure.  But my point is that they didn't think about whether to only ban specific problematic models, nor whether other less-publicized devices might have the same problem.  It was just a matter of "there have been high-profile incidents of some hoverboards catching fire, so we will ban all hoverboards".

Comment: @NateEldredge Banning specific models would be a nightmare. They'd need to inspect things, need some system for certifying models as safe, run the risk of people putting the stickers of a safe brand on an unsafe hoverboard, ...

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes, if they started that it would have to extend to guns that can't fire, oxygen cylinders that are safe, water based paints, spent fireworks, etc. I have certain policies in my business, and sometimes clients try to argue against them, so I politely say: that is my policy.

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange questions are expected to demonstrate some attempt at initial research, no matter how elementary.

Comment: @NateEldredge a big problem with the idea of "banning specific models" was that the ones that caught fire were almost-unbranded models turned out by factories that didn't know what they were doing.  The ban would never keep up with the plethora of such brands popping up to exploit a fad.

Comment: @choster [citation needed]

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**No joke**.  A hoverboard these days isn't referring to flying skateboards a la Marty McFly in *Back to the Future*, but what Wikipedia calls **self-balancing scooters**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_scooter

And the equally serious reason airlines don't want these on board is that they're crammed full of lithium batteries, which have a disturbing tendency to combust violently.  Bad enough when you're out on the street, but much worse if they're in the hold of a passenger aircraft.

By comparison, the lithium batteries in laptops, cellphones and power packs are smaller and usually brought into the cabin, making dealing with any potential fires somewhat easier.

Comment: _That's_ called a hoverboard these days? How boring.

Comment: @leftaroundabout at one point there was another thing called hoverboard - it was super-loud, it only worked on copper floors, it couldn't actually lift off the ground (it hovered at a fixed distance), and it had a tendency to start spinning wildly after a while.

Comment: Here's a good recent article that explains _how_ and _why_ lithium batteries tend to explode on planes (and some research into fixing that problem): [New electrolyte recipe keeps lithium-ion batteries from catching fire](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/08/new-electrolyte-recipe-keeps-lithium-ion-batteries-from-catching-fire/)

Comment: It's not just that laptop etc batteries are smaller, but the cells inside tend to be made by reputable manufacturers such as Panasonic. Whereas these so-called hoverboards are stuffed with cheap no-name 18650s without adequate safety circuits

Comment: Aren't lithium batteries of that capacity banned anyway, so that the ban on hoverboards is redundant and just for clarification? Or could you theoretically transport such a battery if it was in a different kind of device?

Comment: re. phones, note that the Galaxy Note 7 *was* banned from many airlines because of excessively combustible tendencies.

Comment: @leftaroundabout if you want a proper hoverboard, google for _windfoil_ :D

Comment: Just as an addendum to this - toys like Hoverboards are also RIFE with dangerous counterfeits. Given that such battery tech can be volatile at the best of times, the average rip off one is very sketchy indeed

Comment: Where I come from, these are usually called gyroscooters. Maybe worth putting that term in the answer as well.

Comment: Also, any spare lithium ion batteries cannot go in the cargo hold.

Comment: @jdm Some airlines ban hoverboards even if the batteries are removed. (I assume because they don't want to get into the business of checking that the batteries have indeed been removed.)

Answer (score 29):

> Is this a standard text?

Absolutely. Every airline I looked at had such a restriction and I think it's more or less mandated by IATA's restrictions on lithium batteries.

[Air Canada](https://www.aircanada.com/uk/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/restricted-and-prohibited-items.html): "Small lithium battery-powered vehicles are not accepted in either checked baggage or carry-on baggage due to safety concerns associated to the lithium batteries that power them. Prohibited vehicles include: hoverboards, AirBoards, electric skateboards, airwheels, mini-Segways, balance wheels, battery-assisted bikes and electric scooters. Motorized luggage (e.g. Modobag) is also prohibited."

[Air France](https://www.airfrance.com.br/BR/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/produits-interdits-et-reglementes-airfrance.htm#9-electric-transport-vehicles-other-than-those-meant-for-people-with-reduced-mobility): "Lithium battery-operated segways, hoverboards, self-balancing hoverboards, Oxboards, electric skateboards, waveboards, motorized baggage (no matter the battery power in Wh and even if the battery has been disconnected or removed)" are not allowed in either checked or carry-on baggage.

[British Airways](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions): "Due to the potential fire risk associated with lithium batteries, hoverboards and other self-propelled electrically-powered vehicles such as Air Wheels, Solo Wheels, skateboards, scooters and Hover Karts are completely forbidden."

[Japan Airlines](http://www.jal.co.jp/en/dom/baggage/limit/Y15/img/attention.pdf?_ga=2.195926636.1178052621.1537637280-740451728.1537637280): 
"Personal Movement Devices with Built-in Lithium or Lithium Ion Batteries (Except for battery-powered wheelchairs and mobility aids)" are "prohibited in both carry-on and checked baggage even if the batteries are removed, or those devices sold at the airport duty free shops."

[United](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/inflight/devices.html): "In the interest of safety for our customers and employees, we do not accept hoverboards as checked or carry-on baggage."

> Does it have some actual precedent, is it a deliberate allusion to the don't stuff beans up your nose trope, or just a flat-out joke?

It has actual precedent. Hoverboards use high-capacity lithium batteries and such batteries are strictly restricted on flights because they can cause very intense fires if they're damaged, overcharged, undercharged or have manufacturing defects.

At least two cargo flights have crashed because of lithium battery fires: [UPS flight 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPS_Airlines_Flight_6) and [Asiana 991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiana_Airlines_Flight_991).

> Why don't they give something actually realistic as example for the hazards a hoverboard would bring?

Delta don't give examples of why anything else would be dangerous, so why single out hoverboards? It's tough enough getting people to read these things anyway but adding a little essay about each individual item will make the text even longer and guarantee that people won't read it.

Comment: Because in the OP mind, an hoverboard may be a **fictional** item: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoverboard

Comment: @Cœur Sure but that had already been covered in the answer that was posted before mine.

Comment: I was answering your "_why single out hoverboards?_"

Comment: @Cœur Ah. I meant why should Delta single out hoverboards, not the asker.

Comment: @Cœur Ohhhh. But I thought the asker just meant “Why don’t they explain the hazards of hoverboards?” but they probably meant “Why don’t they instead ban some non-fictitious item that would cause the same problems?”

Comment: I think it is also a matter of capacity. You are allowed up to 100Wh by regulations (without special permit, which may allow 160Wh) and hoverboards with their ~200Wh are undeniably above that.

Comment: Interesting is the Air France's "and even if the battery has been disconnected or removed". So, if all the risk is related to the batteries, _how_ these items can be dangerous _without them_?

Comment: @trolley813 Because "disconnected" means the potentially dangerous battery is still there and "removed" means they need to train all their check-in staff to correctly inspect hoverboards to make sure that the battery really has been removed. And that _all_ the batteries have been removed.

Answer (score -6):

Put the devices in a sealed bag full of CO2 or other flame negating gas- end of story. The real issue of collusion against personal mobility devices is the reason why airlines flat out ban self-balancing scooters.

Comment: I'm not really sure what "collusion" you're describing. Personal mobility devices don't compete with airlines—nobody decides to ride a hoverboard 3,000 miles instead of fly—so there's no reason why airlines would collude against them. Regardless, the bans do not permit devices inside of sealed bags of CO2 (nor is there sufficient evidence that could contain a battery fire), so that would still be prohibited.

Comment: Yes. For starters, metal burns can happily continue in a CO₂ atmosphere – at least magnesium, aluminium and sodium, lithium probably as well. If anything, argon would help. But anyways the problem only starts when the batteries overheat (which they can easily do anærobically), and then they could also melt or explode their way through a sealed bag.

Comment: @leftaroundabout completely agree.  My first thought on reading Mr. Valls' suggestion that a CO₂ atmosphere would prevent any combustion was that his knowledge of industrial chemistry was [insufficient](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/02/26/sand_wont_save_you_this_time).